# How to check if specific number of rows exists without count(*)

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-performance

I know we can check if at least one row of a table exists using **EXISTS** keyword, for example:

```
select * from A where exists(select from B where B.id = A.id)
```

What if I want to check if at least **N** rows exist, without using **COUNT**?

Performance matters to me. I don't want the whole table to be scanned to count matching rows. I just need my query to stop when **N** rows are found. I mean, the existence of at least **N** rows is what matters, and not the total count. That could save time if table is large.

Is there such feature in PostgreSQL?

Comment: Have you tried `having count(*) >... ` What indexes do you have on A and B?

Comment: @Lennart :  I am trying to avoid count(*) for performance issues. I don't have indexes because they are temporary tables which are created at the beginning of a function and dropped at the end of it.

Comment: My question was more like, do know for sure that having count means bad performance? You can create indexes even if its temporary tables

Comment: I will give index a try. But when to create it? right after creating the temp table?

Comment: After filling the table(s)

Comment: Well, in my case there is no use of that, because queries on my temp table are performed between inserts on that table

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add this in the `EXISTS` subquery:

```
LIMIT 1 OFFSET (N-1)
```

In other words, the subqery first tries to finds (N-1) rows, skip them and return the next (Nth) row. So, it will return something (one row) if and only if there are N+ rows.

You need appropriate indexes, i.e. an index on `B(id)` in this case, to make it as fast as possible, obviously.

Comment: why not LIMIT N ?

Comment: I tried both your answer and (LIMIT N) in a simple query. As a result set, the difference is obvious... Is there a difference in performance?

Comment: Why not LIMIT N: If you don't have OFFSET, a subquery with `EXISTS (SELECT ... LIMIT N)` will return true if there is at least 1 row, no matter the N value.